# Node JS stack. HAving trouble posting ejs data through Jquery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, post, ejs

I'm trying to Post data that's in ejs tags through Ajax using Jquery. Here is my code. It is very much obviously wrong lol

Could anyone give me pointers in how to do this correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".subscribeButton").click(function(){
  var userId = "";

   userId = '<%=guest.userId%>';

   var forumId ="";

   forumId="<%=topic.forumId%>";

  $.post("/subscriptions",
  {
    userId: userId,
    forumId: forumId
  },
  function(data, status){
    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help you a bit:

```
let ejs = require('ejs');
$(document).ready(() => {
$(".subscribeButton").click(() => {

let userId = ejs.render('<%=guest.userId%>');
let forumId = ejs.render('<%=topic.forumId%>');

$.post("/subscriptions", {
    userId,
    forumId
  },
  (data, status) => {
    console.log(`Data: ${data}\nStatus: ${status}`);
  });
 });
});
```

But it's hard to tell with no HTML or controller function...